# Service or background thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have created a bluetooth tic tac toe application in android. As I am not familiar with android, I learned by reading source codes on the net. As of now how it works is like this:

- Activity 1 > displays new game, about, exit. nothing much here
- Activity 2 > listview with buttons make discoverable and find devices. The user touches on a discovered device and connection is established. Another button is available to exchange player names, and one more button to go to the next activity
- Activity 3 > decide which player goes first. 3 buttons corresponding to rock, paper, scissor, another button to exchange the info, and a button to go to next activity
- Activity 4 > actual game. Some logic(it's not ordinary tic tac toe), but basically on user touch it makes calculations, sends across an integer and waits for data in return.

To implement the communication I have 3 threads: serverThread to listen for connections, connectThread to connect to a device and commsThread to send and receive data. After connection is established only the commsThread is needed. Now this is where I lose clarity. I have an object of type commsThread in the Game class, I call commsThreadObject.start() in Activity 2 once connection is established and I keep this thread running till the application exits. On each activity, I pass a handle belonging to that activity to the commsThread.

Now the code does work for me, but it just doesn't feel neat(in fact feels like very dirty code). Anything other than updating the UI from the handler requires static objects, so I ended up converting a lot of things to static. Also I understand that keeping a thread running like this can result in memory leaks. Now I am learning about services, I just wanna know if that is the right way to do this?

Also in earlier experiments I simply had a single activity and switched layouts on button click. Is that a good approach?

This is the code for my handler in Game class.

```
static Handler receiveCell = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        int numOfBytesReceived = msg.arg1;
        byte[] buffer = (byte[]) msg.obj;
        String strReceived = new String(buffer);
        strReceived = strReceived.substring(0, numOfBytesReceived);
            gameInstance.changeSymbol();
            int x = Integer.parseInt(strReceived);
            int cur = gameInstance.curCell;
            boardGroup[cur].put(x % 3, x / 3, gameInstance.current);
            gameInstance.state = boardGroup[cur].checkLines();
            gameInstance.checkState(cur % 3, cur / 3);
            gameInstance.changeSymbol();
            gameInstance.curCell = x;
            if (boardGroup[x].emptyBlock() == 0) {
                numPad.enableInput();
            } else {
                boardGroup[x].enableInput();
            }
            currentTurn.setText(playerName);
        }
    };
```

As you can see there's quite a bit in my handler. I had to make all the variables referenced here static. Instead is there anyway I can move this out of the handler. Maybe some way to know when a message has received? Something like a local `strReceived.wait()` and `strReceived.notify()`?

Comment: Sounds like you've got a lot going on! It's generally best to show code, so if that's possible it'd be great. But please don't show much or people won't read it. As a first guess- it sounds like you probably don't need to be using `Thread` objects. Quite often, people overlook `java.util.concurrent` (which is a shame because it makes for much better code).

Comment: Service is the way to maintain jobs working without UI interface. do you need to maintain the bluetooth connection even when the app is not on foreground?

Comment: No I need the connection only as long as the game is running.

Comment: And the reason I didn't post code is because it probably won't make sense without all of it :( However I'll try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if your screens are logically different (like splash/setting/main/about) then it makes sense to make them different activities - so that as your app becomes more complex you still don't get a monster class that does way too much.

As for thread vs service - if you manage your thread properly (disconnect socket and kill thread in onPause() and bring it back in onResume(), etc...) then there's no problem with your approach. However, if you want to receive data in background or for some other reason have a more complex lifecycle then Services are your thing.