# Android bluetooth rock paper scissors

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have created a tic tac toe app (mentioned in a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131119/service-or-background-thread)). Now I use a rock paper scissors part in this. Right now how I have done it is have 3 buttons corresponding to rock, paper, scissors and one more button that must be pressed when each player has made their choice. Internally when any of the rock/paper/scissor button is pressed a message gets sent, it is received by a handler and stored into a string on the other device. When the player presses the 4th button, the game does the logic and displays the result.

Now I want to get rid of the 4th button. That is when I press rock/paper/scissor, it should either wait for the other player to make his choice or if he has already made his, display result immediately. How can I achieve this? Is there anyway to wait for a message to receive on the handler (other than busy waiting)?
Here is the code for my handler:

```
static Handler receiveChoice = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        int numOfBytesReceived = msg.arg1;
        byte[] buffer = (byte[]) msg.obj;
        String strReceived = new String(buffer);
        strReceived = strReceived.substring(0, numOfBytesReceived);
        opponentChoice = strReceived;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to learn about [`wait/notify`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29). You can have the first-to-send side sleep until it hears an answer from the other one. You'll want to make sure that your logic that decides whether to sleep is synchronized (with `synchronized`, `volatile`, or with an atomic variable) with the logic processing incoming events.

Comment: Yes I learned a bit about wait and notify. I thought I would do `while(opponentChoice == null) opponentChoice.wait();` But I am having a doubt on this, if I make it wait and the opponent takes a long time to make his choice, will that cause an ANR? Secondly since am causing the main thread to sleep, and the handler is defined within it, will the handler also go to sleep?

Comment: The handler for the incoming data should be fired asynchronously. I'm not familiar enough with the Android Bluetooth API to say for sure, but you should either use a callback or an `Intent` listener. I can't speak to the ANR issue.

Comment: Hmm for now I found a simple solution. I just kept two if clauses. `if(opponentChoice != null) makeDecision();` after I write the data and `if(playerChoice != null) makeDecision();` in the handler after message is received. Haven't tested it, but should work I suppose