# ListActivity or Normal Activity

Tags: android, android-listview

I am developing a tic tac toe game in android (mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131119/service-or-background-thread) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134757/android-bluetooth-rock-paper-scissors)). There are 3 activities, one each for Bluetooth device discovery, rock/paper/scissor, and the actual game. I have a base class that extends `Activity` and contains some common static resources. Each of the three activities I need extend this base class.

Now the problem is I need a `ListView` for the bluetooth activity. The other two activities don't need this. As far as I understand, I can either make the base class extend `ListActivity` and have an empty list element in the layouts for rock/paper/scissor and game. Or I can implement the ListView manually inside bluetooth activity only. Which of these approaches should I take, or is there some other solution altogether?

Comment: use ListActivity its an easy and simple one.

Comment: Use ListActivity and move those common resources to separete static class so you dont have to extend Activity with your base class.

Comment: So I extend the base classes with ListActivity, Activity, Activity and access the static resources without extending from that class? Hmm. One more reason I decided to have a base class was so that I could have a common onResume(), onPause() and onDestroy().

Comment: Why do you not use Fragments instead? Then you could have one Activity and several Fragments. Then you can have a ListFragment where you implement your ListView. Communicate with callbacks between your activity and the fragments.

Comment: Just googled it and I understand what you mean. Are there any limitations to using fragments? I mean why use activities at all if most things are possible with fragments?